# About hibernate inheritance mapping, why an entity can live without a table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

in hibernate inheritance mapping, JPA table-per-class strategy,

the root entity don't need a table to mapping,

sub entity do, and each sub entity has a table.

In my understanding, an entity is: a java class with a mapping config that should mapping to a table,

so how can a root entity exist as an entity without a table to mapping?

if it don't need an table to mapping, why not we use a @**mappedSuperclass** ?

Can we use this root entity to query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root entity doesn't need a table if you don't want to have instances of the root entity.

For example, if you have a base Message class which has two subclasses Email and VoiceMessage, and only want instance of Email and VoiceMessage, there's no reason to have a table for Message, since you'll never create any instance of Message: only of Email or VoiceMessage.

What makes it very different from MappedSuperclass is that you can still have a toOne or toMany association to the base class Message. For example, you could have a Sender entity having a set of sent Messages. And you can create queries over the root Message entity. Such queries would of course return instances of VoiceMessage or Email.

Comment: can we use this root entity in  polymorphic query?

Comment: *And you can create queries over the root Message entity*. So the answer is yes.